# Can an issue be blamed for something?

Tags: word-choice

Can I say:

> Many issues can be blamed for this ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. Some examples:

- *Identity issues can be blamed for adolescent depression…*
- *Mechanical stability issues were blamed for the collapse of the structure…*